# add scrollbar to popup window in IE after opening window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

i want to add scrollbar to popup window after opening it.
In FireFox there is a property 'window.scrollbars', but IE doesn't have such property, 
how can i add scrollbar in IE using javascript?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use css overflow:scroll; property.

To access it by JavaScript, use:

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
```

Comment: document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll' adds scroll to body, not to window, it differs from window scrollbar

Comment: I know it's different, but it's the only cross-browser way of doing this. Most browsers don't allow javascript accessing some window properties, for privacy purposes. What are you trying to achieve?